# Drawings of high-dimensional hypercubes?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, recreational-mathematics, visualization

Do you guess what you see here?

[image]

It's the graph of the 8-dimensional hypercube which is drawn as 16 copies of the 4-dimensional hypercube (or [tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract)).

[image]

All $4n$-dimensional hypercubes can be drawn in the same way, yielding a series of fractal patterns.

I wonder if this kind of drawing can already been found somewhere, and if it has been generalized for other than $4n$-dimensional hypercubes -- and possibly hypertetrahedra?

Comment: [+1] Good idea to connect the 4-cube to the 8-cube. Striking image. I was about to ask a question about simplexes inscribed in this kind of cubes. How have you obtained this kind of projection ?

Comment: You are perfectly right, I apologize for having rung the alarm bell ! Besides, I still have the intention to produce a question that has some similarities with yours...

Comment: You surely have seen [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-cube) Wikipedia entry... which doesn't mention your particular projection.

Comment: [This](https://www.pngwing.com/en/free-png-zktpx) representation is close to yours.

Comment: @JeanMarie:  Thanks for the links! The other representation is definitely the same as mine, how did you find it? (I've played around with it, but the coordinates were a bit easier to calculate for mine.)

Comment: I found it by asking Google "8-cube hypercube", then selecting "images" : it was among the first proposed images.